# BootStrap Modal + JS/AJAX Checkbox Form Submission

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, checkbox

I have spent close to the entire day trying to figure this out on my own, but I am still new to AJAX/JS and failing so I would appreciate any pointers.

I have a list of checkboxes that are in a modal (bootstrap) all with the same name. I want the user to click the relevant checkboxes and submit without redirecting the page. I have been trying to do this through JS and AJAX, but there is obviously something I am missing.

The form inside of the BS modal is as follows.

```
<form method="POST" id="hmis105">
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="reporting[]" value="80">Leishmaniasis</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="reporting[]" value="81">Lymphatic Filariasis (hydrocele)</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="reporting[]" value="82">Lymphatic Filariasis (Lympoedema)</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="reporting[]" value="83">Urinary Schistosomiasis</label>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="ConsultationID" value="{$ConsultationID}" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit">Save</button>
```

I have tried so many methods of Javascript, but this is the one I am trying to use now.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    var hmis = new Array();
    $('input[name="reporting[]"]:checked').each(function() {
        hmis.push(this.value);
    });
var ConsultationID = $(this).attr('ConsultationID');
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/ajax_add_reporting_hmis105.php",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {hmis : hmis, ConsultationID : ConsultationID},
    });
});
```

});

Finally this is the ajax file. I have omitted the php opening tags and DB connection info. $db just creates a new database connection

```
foreach ($_POST['hmis'] as $report) {
    $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $data = array(
        'consultationId' => $_POST['ConsultationID'],
        'diseaseId' => $report,
        'EntryTime' => $now
        );
    $reported = $db->insertRow("database", "table", $data);
}
```

Honestly at this point I am banging my head against the wall and I am re-reading things which only confuses me more >:( Thanks for your time!

Comment: I have also tried using $('#hmis105').serialize() as the data in the javascript too, but this didn't appear to work either... or I was doing something wrong (quite probable).

Answer (score 0):

On the serverside the POST parameter `hmis` will just be a string. To extract the data from it you'll need to use [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
foreach (json_decode($_POST['hmis']) as $report) {
   // ...
```